# Finding closest marker to user location Leaflet KNN

Tags: leaflet, geojson, html, leaflet-plugins

I am using Leaflet KNN and would like the closest station to a users location, from the web browser, to have a pop up saying it is their closest station.
How can I find the nearest marker to the user location?

Using KNN I am currently able to find the closest station to the coordinates of a users mouse click, I am also able to find the users location but not the closest station to the users location.

```
//User location
var Position, Accuracy;
function onLocationFound(e) {
  if (Position) {
    Leafmap.removeLayer(Position);
    Leafmap.removeLayer(Accuracy);
  }

  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
  //pop up stating the users position
  Position = L.marker(e.latlng)
    .addTo(Leafmap)
    .bindPopup(
      "<h4>You are here</h4><p>You are  within " +
        radius +
        " metres from here</p>"
    )
    .openPopup();
  Accuracy = L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(Leafmap);
}

//error message if user location cannot be found
function onLocationError(e) {
  alert(e.message);
}
//display the layers to the map
Leafmap.on("locationfound", onLocationFound);
Leafmap.on("locationerror", onLocationError);

//locate function
function locate() {
  Leafmap.locate();
}
// call locate every 10 seconds... forever
setInterval(locate, 10000);

content_index = leafletKnn(contentLayer);

Leafmap.fitBounds(contentLayer.getBounds());

Leafmap.on("click", function (ev) {
  var nearestResult = content_index.nearest(ev.latlng, 1)[0];

  nearestResult.layer.bindPopup("I am your closest station!").openPopup();
});
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @TomazicM How do I find the closest marker to the user location?

Comment: Then please edit your question and explain more in details what do you mean by "Using KNN I have currently got this working via a click on the map where it will find the closest station to a click and I have the user location separately". It's not clear now what is working and what is not working or is missing.

Comment: I haven't used this yet but assuming 'contentLayer' is an L.geoJson layer - from the API 
 https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn var nearestMeResult = content_index.nearest(e.latlng,1)[0];  will give you the point nearest e.latlng

Comment: @TomazicM IS that clarification any better?#

Comment: @CaryH I thought so too, but I cannot seem to get this to work

Comment: Yes, it's better.

Comment: You write " I thought so too, but I cannot seem to get this to work". Please edit your question and add code of what you have tried and did not work.